# UX exercise/ method to determine menu entries for an application?

Tags: menu

Are there any UX exercises to determine what menu items may be missing in an application. Also any methods to best group menu entries in an application?

Answer (score 1):

We as designers don't always know everything about the product. Even the product owner sometimes lacks full knowledge. The best way to fill those knowledge gaps is to ask the users what they feel and do when they use the product. And the best way to know that from users is through observations and interviews (focus groups, 1-on-1 interviews, etc.)
When you ask large enough users some questions, you begin to get a lot of information on the product that you didn't know before, and once you have that information, you begin to make sense of it through different analyzing activities (card sorting, empathy mapping, storyboardig, SWOT analysis, etc.)

UX exsercises to determine missing menu items:

- User Interviews.
- Observations and follow-up questions.
  [These help you gather information from users.]

UX exercise to group menu entries:

- Card Sort.
  Card sort helps you organize information into groups/buckets. This helps you to make sense of the huge data and categorize them.
  [These help you analyze that information]

Comment: Can you help our question asker understand why these are good methods?

Comment: Thank for the info. Any strategies when a command belongs in a context menu vs the main menu?

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's context or main menu. The strategy remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would firstly take a look at the **sitemap** for your application and verify if every page is accessible in some way through the menu.

After confirming that each page is accessible, you can perform a **card** **sorting** exercise on the menu (open would be more useful in this case) and then re-organise the categories according to results.

Finally, you could conduct a **tree** **test** to ensure the changes you carried out were effective and **iterate** the tests if needed.

Answer (score 0):

What menu items may be missing in an application: look at the tasks the users have to/want to perform with the application: are there clear starting points for all of them?

During early tests: ask users if they are missing something - that is only an indication, of course, not necessarily something you have to do.

Grouping menu entries: do card sorting with different groups, create a menu tree and then do tree testing on it.

Comment: Thank you, are there other methods if user interviews are not available at this point?






Are there other methods if user interviews are not available at this point?

Answer (score 0):

Test it on users and probe them specifically on the menu issue. Hopefully you get answers. If you find no issues, your menu is fine, why look for more problems when they don't exist? Assuming you have covered all the task requirements from

-Task analysis
-BPMN from Product Manager

Place a clear feedback flow to allow users to communicate any issues.
Interview users and probe for missing items in the menu